# Inline python code in latex

Tags: code, inline

I am trying to add some inline python code into my report with color in an box like following:

[image]

As you can see "matrix text is red coloured embedded in a box"
I can add inline colour code using the following method:

```
CVXOPT extends the built-in Python objects with two matrix objects: a {\color{red}\texttt{matrix}} object for dense
```

Which produces the following output:
[image]

It is almost perfect except a box around the code. How I can have a box around the code?

Comment: Hi, ya it is close to my requirement. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply put it inside an `\fbox{...}`:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\pyobject}[1]{\fbox{\color{red}{\texttt{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

CVXOPT extends the built-in Python objects with two matrix objects: a \pyobject{matrix} object for dense

\end{document}
```

[image: Output, square corners]

Or, if you want rounded corners, use `\ovalbox{...}` from the [`fancybox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancybox) package:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor,fancybox}

\newcommand{\pyobject}[1]{\ovalbox{\color{red}{\texttt{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

CVXOPT extends the built-in Python objects with two matrix objects: a \pyobject{matrix} object for dense

\end{document}
```

[image: Output, rounded corners]